# DrawingImage rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, drawimage

I have a DrawingImage containing some GeometryDrawings as a static resource.

Now, if I use the same static resource in a (usercontrol in a) listbox, will it only be rendered *once* or will it be rendered for each instance of the image in the listbox?

If the latter, is it possible to somehow render it only once? I'd rather not have my program perform poorly if there are many items in my list.

Comment: ["premature optimization is the root of all evil"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: Erh...no...I prefer to ensure these things won't become a problem.

Comment: Ok, joke apart, how do you know that possible multiple rendering of the DrawingImage will ever become a performance problem? Right now, it's just an unproven assumption, besides that it might not even occur.

Comment: I don't know that it will be, but if it is rendered each time, I'd like to know how to do it only once. If I have, say 50 of the same image, I see no reason to make the same calculations 50 times when one will suffice

Comment: But keep in mind that 50 times zero is still zero (or 50 times a tiny bit is still a tiny bit)